# Simple integration of Bing Maps into WPF application page

Tags: wpf, bing-maps

How would I go about integrating Bing Maps into a page or frame in my WPF application?  I have found a lot of resources for Bing Maps development, but I don't need to develop with Bing Maps, just add the actual thing into my application without hyper-linking out to the website.

Windows 8 applications do this with "contracts" with other metro apps but I do not see a similar functionality with WPF applications.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go here and download the control :)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx
The control is in the "Bing Maps WPF Control SDK"

If i remember correctly you will need to register for an api key.

UPDATE:
to get the api key you have to register here https://www.bingmapsportal.com/

Answer (score 1):

This was a lot easier than I expected, @Tjofras had a correct answer but here is some more elaboration:

1) Get a Bing Maps developer key for free here - https://www.bingmapsportal.com/
There is a trial version that gives you all the features, but for a limited time and there is a basic version that is free but has limited features.

2) Create a project in Visual Studio for Desktop

3) Check out this article for step-by-step instructions and the exact lines of code to integrate it into your project.

- This line goes at the top of your MainWindow.xaml page :

  *xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"*
- Add the map into your existing grid with your developer key, initial latitude and longitude values, and an initial zoom level with the tags:

m:Map object

CredentialsProvider tag (your developer license code)

Center tag (initial latitude and longtitude)

ZoomLevel tag (how zoomed in you are)

- Browse the API's and make your application awesome!